# Is $|x|$ everywhere differentiable in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Is $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: z \mapsto |z|$ anywhere differentiable? I suppose not in 0 because the restriction of the function to $\mathbb{R}$ isn't.

Comment: What do the Cauchy-Riemann equations tell you about this? Note that $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ are both $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$|z|$ is nowhere complex differentiable, because the only purely real valued complex differentiable functions are constant. But it is (real) differentiable everywhere but in $z=0$, because in essence it is just the distance function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R,\vec x\mapsto \|\vec x\|$. In this case your are just computing its gradient $\mathrm{grad}\,f$, which is $$\mathrm{grad}\,f=\frac{\vec x}{\|\vec x\|}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the restriction of $|z|$ to $\mathbb R$ is not differentiable at $0$, the function $|z|$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Outside $0$, it is easier to deal with $|z|^2$, since there are no square roots involved. If $z=x+yi$, then $|z|^2=x^2+y^2=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$, with $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $v\equiv0$. But the Cauchy-Riemann equations tell us that your function can only be differentiable at those points $(x,y)$ such that $2x=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0$ and that $2y=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0$. Therefore, $|z|^2$ is not differentiable anywhere in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, and so the same thing occurs with $|z|$.